# array of functions, names, and arguments

Tags: c

I'm trying to use function that input (from file) - by they names.

For example - In the file I wrote

```
     functionOne(1,2)
```

I successed to separate the function name and his arguments to different array - now I have:

```
    funcName[] = functioOne
    funcArg[0] = 1
    funcArg[1] = 2
```

But, now I stuck - how I can use it? I tried to make an array of pointers to the functions, but Have not idea how to use it. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude.: The function name is in a file..it's not possible

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it: give some motivation and context (what kind of program are you coding, why do you ask) and if possible some [MCVE], or at least the actual C code (not pseudo-code) you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C doesn't have [*introspection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection). It's not possible, during runtime, to get or call a function from a string.

There are workarounds though. For example you can create a table containing the name of the function and a pointer to the function. Then you can search this table to find the function to call.

Perhaps something like

```
void functionOne(int arg1, int arg2)
{
    ...
}

struct
{
    char *name;
    void (*function)(int, int);
} functions[] = {
    { "funcitonOne", &functionOne },
};
```

To make it more generic, when you have many functions taking different amount of arguments, it's a little harder. Then you could instead of passing arguments like normal, pass an array containing the arguments:

```
void functionOne(int *arguments)
{
    // arguments[0] is the first arguments, etc.
    ...
}
```

Modify the function pointer in the structure accordingly.

If the types of arguments differ as well, then you could use structures with a type-tag and a union for the values.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do the thing you want in C. The closest you can do is, keep an array of function pointers which will be pointing towars the respective functions. Also keep a array of strings which is exactly as per the same index as that of other array. Now whenever you get a function name - you just parse it, compare and get the appropriate function pointer based on the index of the matched string.

How to send the arguemnts - well to do that I would say you go about this - when you know which function you will have to call, you parse the arguments from the file itself (You will know that this function will take 2 arguemnts - so you will get the line and parse it to `int` and `double` as it is expected and then you will call it accordingly).

Comment: Sound good, but how I can "send" the arguments to the function using this method?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In general, **you cannot do what you want in *portable* C11** (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), as explained by others: **function names are a *compile-time* thing** and are unknown at execution time. The C programming language doesn't have [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) and/or [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection). BTW, a function might even "disappear" during [optimized compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (so don't "practically" exist at runtime, but your program behaves [as-if](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule) that function exists), in the sense that it has been [inlined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) or removed from the [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable). However, C has [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) (whose type describes the signature of the indirectly called function); practically speaking, they point to [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code).

---

But if you code an application program on an [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) computer running e.g. Linux, you might *sometimes* have some workarounds, using some "dirty" tricks, specific to that [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture):

- given some *string* like `"functionOne"` (practically, of type `const char*`), you could get a function pointer to it (e.g. the `functionOne`, provided it has extern [linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_(software))) -thru dynamic linking facilities- using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) with a `NULL` path, then [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html). BTW the reverse mapping (from addresses to names) is available thru [dladdr(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html).
- given a [function pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) (or actually any *valid* address in your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) pointing inside some *executable* [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment)), you could call it indirectly if the signature of that function is known at compile time (it is given in the type of that function pointer).
- if you want to call an arbitrary function with *arbitrary* signature and arbitrary arguments only known at *run-time*, you might use the [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/). It knows the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) of your system.
- a possible trick is also to emit some temporary file `/tmp/emittedcode.c` containing C code (at runtime), fork a compilation process into a temporary plugin (e.g. `gcc -Wall -O -shared -fPIC/tmp/emittedcode.c -o /tmp/emittedplugin.so`), and [dynamically load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) that temporary plugin `/tmp/emittedplugin.so` with [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html). Be sure to clean the mess (e.g. remove all temporary files, perhaps using [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html)) at program termination.
- perhaps you want to generate some machine code at runtime; then consider also some [JIT compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) library such as [GCCJIT](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit).

If your PC is not running Linux, you might find equivalent stuff for your OS and computer. Read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to learn more about OSes in general. Read the documentation of your particular OS (for Linux, read first the [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) or some newer book on Linux programming, then [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html), [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and related pages).

---

BTW, if you just want to call functions from your program (from names in some input file), you might instead build at initialization some [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (or [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), perhaps a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree)) associating function names to function pointers, like suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48357636/841108) other answer.

Maybe you want some [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) programming language having some [`eval` primitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval). Look into Common Lisp. Be aware of [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/), it is compiling into dynamically generated machine code at most [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) interactions.

Maybe you are writing some [interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) (that is often more difficult and time consuming than you think, read the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)). Consider perhaps embedding and using an existing one, such as [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) or [Lua](http://lua.org/).